# Can I suppress the MLSD with WinSCP .NET assembly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using WinSCP .NET assembly. When I call the `Session.PutFiles` method, it sends the following series of commands:

```
TYPE A
PASV
MLSD
TYPE A
PASV
STOR myfile
```

Is there a way to tell it NOT to send the `MLSD`? (`MLSD` requests the contents of the remote directory be sent back.) At the very least, I don't need this information so it's just wasting bandwidth. I don't even know how I would access it -- maybe WinSCP is doing something with it internally? What worries me more, though, is that I was given very specific specs about the series of FTP commands that I was supposed to send, which includes several non-standard commands, apparently the site at the other end has a customized FTP server. So I don't want an extra command to screw things up.

Answer (score 1):

In the [latest version](https://winscp.net/tracker/1403), with default transfer settings, WinSCP does not use the `MLSD` command.

It's used only with [`OverwriteMode.Resume` or `OverwriteMode.Append`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#overwritemode) to retrieve attributes of the remote file.

Also, WinSCP issues the `MLSD` command once for every destination directory (not for each file).

Comment: This has been [resolved in WinSCP 5.8.2](https://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=1403)